# When does a continuous function's "Fourier series" converge pointwise almost everywhere to the function?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, fourier-series, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a compact topological group.  By the Peter-Weyl theorem, the complex Hilbert space $L^2(G)$ is the Hilbert space direct sum of the spaces of matrix coefficients of all the irreducible representations of $G$.  When $G$ is commutative, these irreducible representations are one-dimensional, and the Peter-Weyl theorem just says that the unitary characters of $G$ form an orthonormal basis of $L^2(G)$.

For example, when $G = \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, the functions $f_n(x) = e^{2\pi i nx}$ are an orthonormal basis of $L^2(G)$.  Thus if $f \in L^2(G)$, then there are unique complex numbers $c_n$, with $\sum\limits_n |c_n|^2 < \infty$, which gives $f$ its Fourier expansion:

$$f = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb Z} c_n f_n$$
where the sum on the right hand side converges in the $L^2$-norm to $f$.  It is a much deeper theorem that when $f$ is continuous, the right hand side also converges *pointwise* to $f$ almost everywhere.

Is the analogue of this deep theorem known for other compact groups?  That is, suppose we take an orthonormal basis $f_i : i \in I$ of $L^2(G)$ via matrix coefficients of irreducible representations as in the Peter-Weyl theorem, so that any $f \in L^2(G)$ has a "Fourier expansion" for uniquely determined $c_i \in \mathbb C$,

$$f = \sum\limits_{i \in I} c_i f_i$$
so the right hand side converges to $f$ in the $L^2$-norm.  Suppose that $f$ is continuous.  Then, do we know that the right hand side converges pointwise to $f$ almost everywhere?

If this is not known in general, is it known for, say, $G = \mathbb A_k/k$ for $k$ a global field?